# max number inputted by user

Tags: c, for-loop, long-integer

I made this simple program that calculates the factorial of a given number. For a number n it is

n * (n-1) * (n-2) ....* (n-(n-1))

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i,n;
long fact=1;
printf("Enter a number: \t")
scanf("%d",&n);
for(i=0; i<=(n-1); i++)
{    if( n==0 || n==1)
      fact =1;
      else
      fact*=i;
 }
 return 0;
 }
```

I realized that the program crashes when the user inputs a large number.(which is logical)

1. I want  the limit of this number. (i.e the max number that can be inputed by the user without crashing the program.)

   Is there a way to increase this number?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are right about crashing. The limit can be determined by if `n!` is less than maximum possible number represented. You should use floating point representation to increase this number

Comment: You should use the limits.h library and check your factorial with the INT_MAX
Please read this link [limits.h][1]. 

  [1]: https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.files/doc/aixfiles/limits.h.htm

Comment: This really shouldn't "crash" no matter what.  Overflowing an integer does not crash a C program.

Comment: @Andrey I don't know about that but I tried it with big numbers and the window turns inactive and nonresponsive. (I am using turbo c++).

Comment: If you let it run long enough it will return.  It is turning inactive because it is running a ton of multiplications.  It hasn't "crashed."

Comment: @Andrey so maybe inhancing the pc and not the program right?

Comment: No.  If your input is big enough, you will overflow the integer object where you are storing the output.  In fact, even if you store the output in a `long`, or a `long long`, if your input is `INT_MAX`, you will overflow the `long`.  I was just pointing out that your code does not *crash*, it just doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @Andrey thanks. Nice information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

generally in c and c++ , the minimum requirements are

```
signed char: -2^07+1 to +2^07-1
short:       -2^15+1 to +2^15-1
int:         -2^15+1 to +2^15-1
long:        -2^31+1 to +2^31-1
long long:   -2^63+1 to +2^63-1
```

so to find out the limit of the number that can be entered, you would have to look for two numbers whose factorials fall just below and just above the range of long, i.e., 2^31 - 1 in the minimal case

to increase this limit, you might consider using `long long`

or maybe `unsigned long long`

Answer (score 1):

try to use scanf("%ld",&n)

or scanf("%lld",&n), also do with printf
or maybe use strings and arrays to work with big numbers

Comment: The problem isn't about n. Since n is too small compared to fact.

Comment: That is I am talking about when I said that you shud use strings for input, and then convert them to array of int, you can find on net algorithms to work with that things if you can't wite them you own

Comment: Here is my code for that in C++, i have wrote it in C, but i can't find it
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tutqavekvywbbh1/BigNumbers.rar